# PHP, trying to make row ID's work

Tags: php

So I basically been coding this quick stat shower for my game server, but I want it to ID numbers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ExileMod Stats</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("******","******","******","******");  //server address, username, password, dbname
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    //check order ascending or descending
    if (isset($_GET["order"])) {
        $sort = $_GET["order"];
        if ($_GET["order"] == "asc"){
            $sort = "desc";
            $order = "asc";
        }
        else{
            $sort = "asc";
            $order = "desc";
        }
    }

    //check filter
    if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
        $name = $_GET["name"];
        }
            else {
            $name = "name";
                }
$list=array('name', 'money', 'score', 'kills', 'deaths', 'uniform', 'vest', 'last_updated_at');
if (in_array($name,$list))
{
    //variable ok
}
    else
    {
        $name = "name";
    }

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM account a INNER JOIN player p ON a.uid = p.account_uid  ORDER BY a.$name $order");
?><!--//echo "<table border='1'>-->
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=name\">Player Name</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=money\">Money</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=score\">Score</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=kills\">Kills</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=deaths\">Deaths</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=uniform\">Uniform</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=vest\">Vest</a></th>";?>
<?php echo "<th><a href=\"?order=$sort&name=last_updated_at\">Last Updated</a></th>";?>
</tr>
<!--//";-->
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?><tr class="danger"><?php
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['money'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['kills'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['deaths'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['uniform'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['vest'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['last_updated_at'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
<a href="http://heroesofgaming.co.uk">© HeroesOfGaming 2016 - 2017</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I am trying to do is put numbers so it counts 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 to however many players are selected from the database? Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<?php

$i = 0; // <--- Added this
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$i++; // <--- Added this
?><tr class="danger"><?php
echo "<td>". $i . "</td>"; // <--- Added this
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['money'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['kills'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['deaths'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['uniform'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['vest'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['last_updated_at'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked or doesn't show any row numbering at all.

Comment: I want to create a colum for ID, going from 1 to whatever the end  number is
Example: 
http://prntscr.com/e29reh

Comment: Great, works. Now how do I get it to filter from ascending to descending?

Comment: by which column? The id is automatically by ascending, if you want another column ordering, you need to add to your MySQL query ORDER BY your_column ASC

Comment: Nevermind, it's not really needed. :) Thank you for your support.

Comment: I have a problem, my last column doesn't show now, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Have you added one more <th> to your table head for ID column?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot an extra <th>, sorry that's my fault. Have a good day Avik, you have been a great support today. :)

Comment: Thanks, have a nice day too ;)